# align-content: flex-end not shifting elements to container bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an `outerWrapper`, `innerWrapper`, and children.

`outerWrapper` has a height of `300px`, and is `display: flex`.

`innerWrapper` is also `display: flex`.

I think because they are `flex`, `innerWrapper` inherits `outerWrappers` height.

I want to add `align-content: flex-end` to `outerWrapper`. But it doesn't work, because `innerWrapper` inherits `outerWrappers` height.

How can I add `align-content: flex-end` to `outerWrapper`?

Or, how can I keep `innerContents` height the same height as its children, so `align-content: flex-end` will work?

Here's an image describing what I want:

[image]

I want to bring `innerContent` down to the red line.

**Update**

I just want to clarify. I want `innerWrapper` to end at the red line, not start.

#### JSFiddle

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <ul id="innerWrapper">
    <li class="child">I'm #01</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #02</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #03</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #04</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #05</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try `align-items:flex-end;` instead of `align-content:flex-end;`.

align-content is for multi line flexible boxes. It has no effect when items are in a single line. It aligns the whole structure according to its value.

The align-items property of flex-box aligns the items inside a flex container vertically just like justify-content does for horizontal axis.

Comment: Oh. Interesting! I'm a bit puzzled by single line though. Does that mean single child, but its grandchild can have as many lines as it wants; will that still be considered single line? Or do all its descendants also have to be single line?

Comment: single line means single row

Comment: What about its descendants? i.e. grandchildren

Comment: sorry don't understand what you want to say?

Comment: It's a bit confusing. I know. :) Let's take the example in the question. Let's say `innerWrapper` has 5 rows. Does that make `outerWrapper` not single lined?

Comment: still it will work align-items:flex-end will adjust its inner items to the end

Comment: @HiralSuvagya, the `justify-content` property doesn't always work on the horizontal axis. It can align vertically, too. It depends on `flex-direction`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Instead of, or in addition to, `align-content: flex-end`, use `align-items: flex-end`.

The `align-content` property only works on multi-line flex containers. So, for instance, if your flex items wrap, then `align-content` would come into play.

In a single line flex container, `align-content` has no effect. As you mentioned, *"... it doesn't work because `.innerWrapper` inherits `.outerWrapper`'s height"*. In other words, it doesn't work because the cross size of a single line is the cross size of the container, leaving no extra space.

*From the spec:*

> [**6. Flex Lines**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines)
>
> In a multi-line flex container (even one with only a single line), the
>   cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the
>   flex items on the line (after alignment due to `align-self`), and the
>   lines are aligned within the flex container with the `align-content`
>   property. ***In a single-line flex container, the cross size of the line
>   is the cross size of the flex container, and `align-content` has no
>   effect.*** The main size of a line is always the same as the main size of
>   the flex container’s content box.
>
> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis. ***Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
>   container.***
>
> *<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>*